# java beginner- in which folder should I place a "database.properties" file

Tags: java, properties

I read some tutorials on how to read data from a database.properties file- which basically stored key-value pairs.

What i want to know is, in which folder should I place this file? Is it in the root (ie "src") or within a package... And how do I access this file, if it is placed in "src"- my code will be within a package (and the package's directory will be under src)- so how do I access the properties file, which is in "src", from a class within a package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally it should be in the external folder(src/main/resources) not along with the .java. 
Use ResourceBundle for reading it.

Answer (score 0):

Best approach is under **src/main/resources**.

Answer (score 0):

Where to place your file is a subjective matter (of which I am no expert.)  However, you should remember that your classpath begins with your project folder implicitly.  Also, you can access your packages the same way as you access a folder on your OS.

So a file in your src package named foo.txt would be : loadingMethod("src/foo.txt")